# How to document the types of arrays in PHPDoc, when those arrays are maps (aka hash tables)?

Tags: php, arrays, dictionary, hashtable, phpdoc

PHPDoc is the adaptation of JavaDoc to PHP.  With the correct syntax in comments, you can use it to document the types of things.  Tools such as IDEs can then use that metadata.

Here's an example using a 'simple' array of strings.

```
/**
  * @param string[] $strings  This parameter is blah blah blah.
  */
public function foo($strings) {
    // ...
}
```

But PHP "arrays" can also be used as maps (aka hash tables aka dictionaries.)  Here's an example from the PHP documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);
```

Now assume we modify our function `foo` to take things like `$array` above: an array of string => string.

```
/**
  * @param ??????? entries  This parameter is blah blah blah.
  */
public function foo($entries) {
    // ...
}
```

How should the type of `$entries` be represented in PHPDoc?

http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html#arrays doesn't even mention such a construct existing in the language.

Comment: I think type of `$entries` should be simply declared as `array`. I think this is a limitation of phpdoc. I guess the intention is to document the structure of the parameter for other developers, not for type hinting reasons while this will never work for arrays. You may write a further documentation in the description. If you want a cleaner solution so you should write a class representing your hashmap `class foobar { public $foo; public $bar; }` and declare your type as foobar. In this case type hinting will work, too.

Comment: I think this continues to be discussed over at https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/issues/7

Comment: [According to phpdoc](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/types.html#arrays), the documentation for arrays is fairly limited. You can make an array unspecified (ie. `@return array`), have a single type (ie. `@return int[]`), or multiple types (ie. `@return (int|string)[]`). However, there is no mention of more complicated arrays, such as associative arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can at least document that `$entries` should be an array of `string`s:

```
/**
 * @param string[] entries
 */
public function foo($entries) 
{
    // ...
}
```

However, you could also modify the method signature to add a type-declaration for `array`:

```
/**
 * @param string[] entries
 */
public function foo(array $entries) 
{
    // ...
}
```

And furthermore, you could guard against invalid values being passed in by either writing your own assertions, or using, for example, [`beberlei/assert`](https://github.com/beberlei/assert):

```
use Assert\Assertion;

/**
 * @param string[] entries
 * 
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function foo(array $entries) 
{
    Assertion::allString($entries);
    Assertion::allString(array_keys($entries));

    // ...
}
```

This doesn't help a lot with the docblock, but it documents the requirements in regard to your parameters in the code itself.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend to avoid using arrays for data structures in PHP code. Classes with explicitly defined properties are much more suitable.

As a workaround you can use stub classes to describe array structure, though you'll need to cast array to object to benefit from this.

```
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

/**
 * @property $foo
 * @property $bar
 */
class MyStub {}

/** @var MyStub $object */
$object = (object)$array;

// IDE completion and inspections are now available
$object->foo .= $object->bar;

// optional casting back to array
$array = (array)$object;
```